# <i> element is invisible outside a region

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wavesurfer.js

I'm using the [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) library with the regions plug-in. I'd like to add a button right above a region that will play it. However, the button shouldn't be inside the region itself, since that will also trigger a `regio-click` event.

I've tried to use a CSS `transform: translateY` to make it appear above the region, but when the button slides off the region it becomes invisible. As you can see in the [demo](http://codepen.io/dimidd/pen/QpJBwM/), only the lower half of the red play button is visible. I've also tried to increase the Z index, but to no avail. Note, that the button needs to be tied to the region element, such that when the region is moved/resized it'll move as well.

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.min.js"></script>
<h2>wave</h2>
<div id="waveform"></div>
<p align="center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    Play
  </button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform',
  waveColor: 'violet'
});

wavesurfer.load('https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');

wavesurfer.on('ready', function() {
    wavesurfer.on('region-created', function(reg) {
        const regElem = $('region[data-id="' + reg['id'] + '"]')[0];
        const playRegion = regElem.appendChild(document.createElement('i'));
        playRegion.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-play";
        playRegion.style = "color: red; transform: translateY(-8px)";
        playRegion.addEventListener('click', function() {
            wavesurfer.play(reg['start'], reg['end']);
       });
   });

  wavesurfer.addRegion({
    start: 2, // time in seconds
    end: 5, // time in seconds
    color: 'hsla(100, 100%, 30%, 0.1)'
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't think you can show overflow in a `canvas`

Comment: @Pete Thanks, is there another way to achieve this result?

Comment: Not too sure, never used the plugin